# Is it possible to rename an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I was just wondering if there is a way to rename the variable assigned to an ArrayList... Or if I just need to create another one, just making it exactly the same.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to rename a variable, but like you said, can copy it to another one.

Comment: What is the problem with renaming current variable? If it is your code you should be able to name your variables however you want.

Comment: Sounds like an instance of the XY problem... (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Simply create a new variable. However, I am unsure why the very naming of your arraylist would truly 'matter' enough to have to rename it during execution...

Comment: There is no way to rename a variable at runtime. What you can do is use IDE refactoring tools to rename a variable (including updating the code locations where it's used). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new reference with the name you want and assign it from the old reference:

```
ArrayList original = ...;
ArrayList newList = original;
```

I should point out that since ArrayList is a reference type, original and newList are both pointing to the same data in memory. If you add an item to original or to newList, it is going to affect both. It is not creating a second copy of the ArrayList. It is a little difficult to understand what you are asking for, though.

If you are talking about refactoring your code to rename the variable across the entire application, then it sort of depends on what IDE you are using, but any good IDE will have this capability.

Comment: if you want to use the `newList` instead of the `original` then this is the way to go! If however you want to use the `newList` while continuing to use the `original` in a different manner, then your `newList` should be a real copy of the `original` rather than just copying the reference (like here)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would just like to point out that 'renaming' a variable is not really a concept that bares any resemblance to the way that changing a '[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409787/object-references-in-java)' or '[identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbuk/index.html)' works. You can't change a variables *identifier* (kind of like a variable's name), but you can pass the variable's value to another variable with a different identifier.

When a variable refers to an `Object` or child of the `Object` class (such as `ArrayList`), your reference type variable holds data indicating the position of that object in memory. So passing that reference's data to another reference just means there are now two `Object` references that '*refer*' to the same object in memory.

Technically speaking, if you wanted to give that object a name that you could use to identify it later with, this is possible by creating a custom class that extends `ArrayList` (or whatever object). For example;

```
public class NamedArrayList extends ArrayList{

    private String listName = "default_name";

    public String getListName(){
        return listName;
    }

    public void setListName(String listName){
        this.listName = listName;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a Wrapper class which holds an `ArrayList` as well as a name for identifying it. Apologies if the last part is a little off subject, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
List<Double> original =new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> copy = new ArrayList<Double>(original);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename any variable while the programm is running.

But you could rename it while developing. Then compile and run.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean by renaming using a different reference than you can simply do

```
ArrayList newListRef = oldListInstance;
//use newListRef thereafter
```

If you mean to change some of the elements retaining the order then -

`ArrayList` is dynamic in size. You can add and remove elements to and from specific index and ordering in retained. So no need to create separate List. If you want to change a specific element simply remove it and add new element at that index.

APIs

```
public E remove(int index)
public void add(int index, E element)
```

Comment: Not that I am downvoter, but it seems that this question is about variable name used to hold ArrayList like `List variableName = new ArrayList()`, not about how to change content of list.